# Upgrading to Java 1.7.0_45 Error - Java does not launch

Tags: windows-7, windows, java, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I'm running into an issue where Java will not launch in IE 9.

Specifically IE 9.0.8.112.16421 Update Version 9.0.21

I am upgrading from version 1.6, i uninstalled version 1.6 then i installed 1.7.0_45.

When I go to a webpage i have confirmed that Java will not start, instead i receive an X where the java applet should be.  Similar to if i did not have Java installed.

I checked my addons in IE and my Java ones are enabled.

When i check event viewer, this is what i see:

> Faulting application name: javaw.exe, version: 7.0.450.18, time stamp: 0x525404d7 
>   Faulting module name: msvcr100.dll, version: 10.0.40219.1, time stamp: 0x4d5f0c22
>   Exception code: 0xc0000417
>   Fault offset: 0x0008af3e
>   Faulting process id: 0x13e4
>   Faulting application start time: 0x01cecb5ab13d3371
>   Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
>   Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\msvcr100.dll

I went to the Microsoft web site, and a forum indicated I needed to install Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86) to get the dll. I did this, but I still get the same error.

I also tried copying the dll from a working system, that did not work either.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks
Paul

Comment: Did you install all updates connected to the `Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package` there is a Service Pack you should also install. I would use http://singularlabs.com/software/javara/ and see if it helps at all.

Comment: @Ramhound I installed both the x84 and x64 Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Service Pack 1 Redistributable. no luck.  I also used the JAVARA uninstaller, it removed all the components of java but after reinstalling it did not work.

Comment: I assume you have tried a system restart?  Those files are also located in your Windows folder I would try copying the 32-bit version located there.

Comment: @Ramhound Tried restarting.  Are you saying copy the dll from system32 to the java folder?

Comment: No.  That would be the 64-bit dll.  You want to replace the dll located in the SysWOW64 folder.